# In WordPress, is adding new fields through the metadata table considered "editing the core?"

Tags: wordpress

We are migrating a CMS into Wordpress.  In particular, I want to know if adding more key/value pairs in teh wp_usermeta table is considred a taboo in that I would be editing the core.  Should I instead have a new table with the extra user values we're importing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding just *data* as key/value pairs in the wp_usermeta table, then that wouldn't necessarily be considered editing core since that table data is engineered to scale.

Rather, if you need to have a different table schema than what the wp_usermeta table offers, than adding an additional table for your data would be worth while.